# How can I improve the runtime of reading multiple excel files using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, runtime

I created function that iterates over a folder containing excel files and creates a list of all the headers across all sheets. I**t works fine but is VERY slow**. Do you have any ideas on how to improve it? THANKS!

```
import glob

# file directory
path = r'C:\Users\John\Excel_folder' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")

def get_columns(file):    
    sheets = pd.ExcelFile(file).sheet_names
    for sheet in sheets:
        for i in (list(pd.read_excel(file, sheet, nrows=0).columns)):
                  col.append(i)
col=[]
for i in all_files:
    get_columns(i)

col
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass `None` to `sheet_name` in `read_excel` to read all sheets at once. It creates a dictionary of dataframe, so at the end you can do with list comprehension.

```
def get_columns(file):
    return [c 
            for df in pd.read_excel(file, 
                                    sheet_name=None, 
                                    nrows=0).values() 
            for c in df.columns]

col = [c for file in all_files for c in get_columns(file)]
```

it should be faster because you open once the file instead of many times.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I never came across a collections.OrderedDict class. how do I access the different elements of it?

Comment: @AlmogWoldenberg I'm not sure what you mean, `pd.read_excel` with sheet_name=None return a regular `dict` for me, but otherwise `OrderedDict` can be used like "regular" `dict`, `items()`, `key()`, `values()` like in the code above, one difference would be to keep the keys in the order they are added into the dict, but other than that I don't know enough about it